# Laravel 5.4 pagination links not showing in the view

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I'm using [Laravel Database: Pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/pagination) to show the links in the blade template. I can view the data in columns but not the links.

This is the controller function I use to pass the data to view.

```
public function showProducts(){

 $products = DB::table('products')->orderBy('created_at')->simplePaginate(9);

  return view('products', ['products' => $products]);
}
```

And this is the view section to show the links.

```
<div class="row text-center">
   <div class="col-lg-12">
      <ul class="pagination">
         {{ $products->links() }}                    
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
<!-- /.row -->
```

[image]

But I can't see any links. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: What is being rendered in the HTML source?

Comment: Remove the <ul> tag

Comment: I removed the UL tag, but still not working.

Comment: @user2094178 I have updated with the screenshot.

Comment: stupid question, but do you have more then one page of the results? Cause pagination will be hidden if there's no page links to show...

Comment: @ivanhoe what if you want to show the links when there aren't enough for more than one page?

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you have 9 products in database.It is possible that not to show if enough data is not available

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
 {{ $products->links() }}
```

with

```
{!! $articles->render() !!}
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score -1):

Hi you have an error in passing a variable to `views`

```
public function showProducts(){

  $products = DB::table('products')->orderBy('created_at')->simplePaginate(9);

  return view('products')->with(products' , $products);
}
```

hope this helps

also run `php artisan vendor:publish` make you have pagination directories in `/views/vendor/`

Comment: But I can see the variables with array passing.

Comment: `view($tpl, ['foo' => 'bar'])` is a valid way to pass variables, has the same effect as using `with()`